# DeadLock Found Error in Batch DELETE Prepared Statement MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am deleting more than 90k rows in my table through JDBC prepared statement.

My code looks like this:

```
 //Open JDBC Connection
 //MYSQl QUERY 
 String fetchDataSQL="DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=? AND X=? AND Y=?";
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(fetchDataSQL);
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

for (Data dt : dataList) {
     preparedStatement.setLong(1, dt.getID());
     preparedStatement.setLong(2, dt.getX());
     preparedStatement.setLong(3, dt.getY());
     preparedStatement.addBatch();
}
preparedStatement.executeBatch();
dbConnection.commit();

//cose prepared statement
//close connection
```

Here `dataList` contains more than  90k record which I want to delete.I had applied mysql indexing also to MYTABLE for id,X,Y

Unfortunately I got error

`Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

I have googled, I did not found working solution.
please help me to find solution or alternative if present.

Thank you

Comment: Why don`t you start first with the documentation, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: Lack is not a number in the English language.

Answer (score 0):

As @bodi0 points out, the MySQL Reference Manual ([14.2.7.9. How to Cope with Deadlocks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)) has lots of advice on how to diagnose deadlocks, and how to deal with them.

In this case I can think of two possible explanations:

- You are deadlocking against some other transaction being performed by a different database connection or a different database client.
- You have entries in the `datalist` that have the same `{ID, X, Y}` values, so you end up adding multiple deletes for the same row or rows to the batch.  Maybe this results in MySQL attempting to lock the same row twice, and deadlocking.  (Just a theory ...)

But a better idea would be to diagnose the deadlock for yourself.